# For an increasing function $f$, if $f(y_n)-f(x_n) \to 0$ , then $f$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continuity, monotone-functions

Question: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be an increasing function. Suppose there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $x_n<0<y_n$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $f(y_n)-f(x_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Attempt: We consider two arbitrary sequences $(a_n)$ with $a_n>0$ which converges to $0$ and $(b_n)$ with $b_n <0$ which converges to $0$ also.

We choose monotone subsequences $(a_{r_n})$ and $(b_{s_n})$. They both converge to $0$ [$(a_{r_n})$ must be monotone decreasing and the other one M.I.] . Again, being a monotone function, $f(0-)$ and $f(0+)$ both exist. Further, we have $f(b_{s_1})\leq f(b_{s_2})\leq...\leq f(b_{s_n})\leq f(a_{r_n})\leq f(a_{r_{n-1}})\leq ...\leq f(a_{r_1})$.

Now, we consider the Nested Intervals:
$I_t=[f(b_{s_t}),f(a_{r_t})]$.

By the given condition $|I_t| \to 0$, as $t\to \infty $.

$\therefore f(0-),f(0+)\in \displaystyle \bigcap_{t=1}^{\infty}{I_t}$

Thereby, $f(0-)=f(0+)$. Again, the function being M.I, $f(0-)\leq f(0)\leq f(0+)$. Hence, $f(0-)=f(0)=f(0+)$

Did I miss anything? Kindly justify the proof. It will be of great help.

Thank You.

Comment: It's a time back I had the course real analysis, however, it seems right from what I remember.

Comment: :(  I am glad that at least a single soul cared to see it.

Comment: I need a more thorough investigation of my steps.

Comment: I think your proof is concise and clear enough.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thank you Sir, for taking your time.